# Python 3.6 : Either I miss something either generic typing breaks super chaining for inheritance

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, super, typing

First I ran the following code, which went real fine :

```
class Monster:
    def __init__(self):
        self._can_do = []
        print("created a monster")
        super().__init__()

class Race(Monster):
    """ all races must derive from this """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("created a race x")

class Human(Race):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Do nothing special !")
        print("created a human")

class Elf(Race):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Avoid sleep")
        print("created an elf")

class Class:
    """ all classes must derive from this """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("created a class x")

class Fighter(Class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Hit hard")
        print("created a fighter")

class Wizard(Class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Cast spells")
        print("created a wizard")


class Hero(Human, Fighter):
    def __init__(self):
        x = super()
        print(f"super = {x}")
        super().__init__() 
    def speak(self):
        for action in self._can_do:
            print(f"I can {action} !")

print("creating hero 1 :")
hero1 = Hero()

print("hero 1 human fighter says :")
hero1.speak()
```

Result was :

```
creating hero 1 :  
created a monster  
created a class x  
created a fighter  
created a race x  
created a human  
hero 1 human fighter says :  
I can Hit hard !  
I can Do nothing special ! !
```

Then I had another go, changing very slightly the code, as below, because that is were I want to go :

*(made the Hero class heriting dynamically instead of statically)*

```
import typing

class Monster:
    def __init__(self):
        self._can_do = []
        print("created a monster")
        super().__init__()

class Race(Monster):
    """ all races must derive from this """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("created a race x")

class Human(Race):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Do nothing special !")
        print("created a human")

class Elf(Race):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Avoid sleep")
        print("created an elf")

class Class:
    """ all classes must derive from this """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("created a class x")

class Fighter(Class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Hit hard")
        print("created a fighter")

class Wizard(Class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._can_do.append("Cast spells")
        print("created a wizard")

RaceT = typing.TypeVar('RaceT', bound=Race)
ClassT = typing.TypeVar('ClassT', bound=Class)

class Hero(typing.Generic[RaceT, ClassT]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
    def speak(self):
        for action in self._can_do:
            print(f"I can {action} !")

print("creating hero 1 :")
hero1 = Hero[Human,Fighter]()

print("hero 1 human fighter says :")
hero1.speak()
```

This time, all went wrong :

```
creating hero 1 :  
hero 1 human fighter says :  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "./test2.py", line 61, in <module>  
    hero1.speak()  
  File "./test2.py", line 54, in speak  
    for action in self._can_do:  
AttributeError: 'Hero' object has no attribute '_can_do'
```

- Seems using generic class creation makes super unable to find parent class initializer, non ?
- Did I miss something ?

Comment: Yes you missed something. That is not what `typing.Generic` is for at all. A generic type is normally used to describe what types a container holds such as `List[int]` or `Tuple[str, float]`

Comment: Your title is bordering on nonsensical

Answer (score 5):

That's not what generic typing means. When you declare

```
class Hero(typing.Generic[RaceT, ClassT]):
    ...
```

then that means that `Hero` takes two type parameters. It *doesn't* mean that `Hero[Human, Fighter]` is a subclass of `Human` or `Fighter`, any more than `List[int]` is a subclass of `int`. Generic typing is not a way to dynamically adjust a class's superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a metaclass solution that allows you to dynamically generate classes from a `Race, Class` pair

```
class Hero(type):
    instances = {}  # All Elf Wizards should have the same class, for example
    @classmethod
    def class_factory(metacls, race, class_):
        if not (issubclass(race, Race) and issubclass(class_, Class)):
            raise ValueError("Needs race and class, got {} and {}".format(race, class_))
        name = "{0.__name__}{1.__name__}".format(race, class_)
        if name in metacls.instances:
            return metacls.instances[name]
        cls = metacls(name, (race, class_), {})   
        metacls.instances[name] = cls
        return cls

ElfWizard = Hero.class_factory(Elf, Wizard)
assert ElfWizard is Hero.class_factory(Elf, Wizard)
tim = ElfWizard()
```

prints

```
created a monster
created a class x
created a wizard
created a race x
created an elf
```